# partition an 1D array into different sized chunks sequentially with numpy

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I would like to partition an 1D array into 2 and 3 sized chunks sequentially
like so:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

[[1,2],
[3,4,5],
[6,7],
[8,9,10]]
```

Comment: Is the length of input array always a multiple of `5`?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution without numpy:

```
z=list(range(1,11))
offset=0
r=[]
p=[2,3]
for i in p*(len(z)//sum(p)):
    r.append(z[offset:offset+i])
    offset+=i

print(r)
```

yields:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9, 10]]
```